# Running a parser within parboiled2

Tags: scala, parsing, parboiled, parboiled2

The docs for parboiled2 mention the following to get results:

https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2#access-to-parser-results

```
val parser = new MyParser(input) 
val result = parser.rootRule.run()
```

However I get a compilation error when attemping what seems to that approach:

Here is the outline of the parser:

```
case class CsvParser(input: ParserInput, delimiter: String = ",") extends Parser {
    ..
   def file = zeroOrMore(line) ~ EOI
}
```

The code to attempt to run it

```
val in = new StringBasedParserInput(readFile(fname))
val p = new CsvParser(in)
println(p.toString)
p.file.run
```

But the "run" is not accepted:

> ```
>  Error:(81, 12) too few argument lists for macro invocation
>   p.file.run
> ```

```
       ^
```

Comment: `val in = new StringBasedParserInput(readFile(fname))` -> there's no need to use this constructor. So you can pass a string inside your csv parser. And it will be converted automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that the problem inside the following line:

```
case class CsvParser(input: ParserInput, delimiter: String = ",")
```

and it can be fixed by explicitly declaring `parserInput` as a val

```
case class CsvParser(val input: ParserInput, delimiter: String = ",")
```